# Meaning of "within two months"

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Led by the guards, Esmeralda hobbled
>   back to the courtroom. Djali’s heartbroken
>   bleating echoed her sorrow.
>   “So, you’ve confessed!” the judge exclaimed.
>   “Good! **Within two months**, you will be taken
>   to the Cathedral of Notre Dame. There you
>   will beg for the forgiveness of your soul. At
>   noon of the same day, you will be taken to the
>   city gallows—along with your goat. Both of
>   you shall be hanged by the neck until dead.
>   May God have mercy on your soul.”
>   “Oh, this must be a dream,” the horrified
>   girl cried out. Rough hands pulled her away.
>   Soon she lay in the dungeon, shivering in
>   the darkness, not knowing whether it was day
>   or night. Drops of rainwater fell on the floor
>   from the cracked ceiling. Esmeralda’s cell was
>   cold, dark, and damp. She had not a single
>   blanket to keep her warm.

Does it mean: after two months?

or does it mean: one day during following two months?

Comment: I think it means *at some point during this period of two months...*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"within two months" means one day during following two months.
"Within" means inside or not further than an area or period of time.